# List index out of range for a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for file in files:
    book=xlrd.open_workbook(file)
    first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    i=0
    j=0
    while first_sheet.cell(14+i,1+j).value != xlrd.empty_cell.value:
        while first_sheet.cell(14+i,1+j).value != xlrd.empty_cell.value:
            val=first_sheet.cell(14+i,1+j)
            print (val, i)
            i=i+1
        i=0
        j=j+1
```

after reading n rows of a column, it is saying list index out of range. Assume, i dono the number of rows and so chose while loop. I could the same in excel vba to run, but here some issues.
Error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User_2\Desktop\Vijay\FAST\KarBarge\Results py-spreadsheets.py", line 28, in <module>
    while first_sheet.cell(14+i,1+j).value != xlrd.empty_cell.value:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 399, in cell
    self._cell_types[rowx][colx],
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Post full error traceback

Comment: Why do you have `while first_sheet.cell(14+i,1+j).value != xlrd.empty_cell.value:` twice?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I have a nxn values. I'm going through each columns and each rows

Comment: @kvorobiev: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User_2\Desktop\Vijay\FAST\KarBarge\Results\py-spreadsheets.py", line 28, in <module>
    while first_sheet.cell(14+i,1+j).value != xlrd.empty_cell.value:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 399, in cell
    self._cell_types[rowx][colx],
IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exception you are getting, and simply want to ignore it, `try: except:` is the way to go.

```
i=0
j=0
try:
  while first_sheet.cell(14,1+j).value != xlrd.empty_cell.value:
    try:
      while first_sheet.cell(14+i,1+j).value != xlrd.empty_cell.value:
          val=first_sheet.cell(14+i,1+j)
          print (val, i)
          i=i+1
    except IndexError:
      # ignore error from iterating in i
      pass
except IndexError:
  # ignore error from iterating in j
  pass
else:
  i=0
  j=j+1
```

Comment: could you please spot the error in the way i wrote. because i could use the same basic way to write in excel vba successfully.?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting `List index out of range` is as you say, you are trying to access a cell in the spreadsheet that does not exist. Simply testing it to see if it is empty would cause this.

`xlrd` can tell you the number of available rows and columns using:

```
print(first_sheet.nrows, first_sheet.ncols)
```

So your loops would need to stay within these bounds.

Your code appears to be attempting to display the contents of the spreadsheet by column. As an alternative approach you could try the following:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"input.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for colx in range(1, sheet.ncols):
    print(sheet.col_values(colx, start_rowx=14))
```

This would print each column as a list of values starting at row `14`.